# Sql SELECT from 2 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 same table with flowing column

```
id,
timestamp,
country,
data
```

`table 1` is storing information for the `country A` , and
`table 2` is storing information for the `country B`

i need to  do `SELECT from both table ORDER BY timestamp`

can anybody help me with best and correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try

```sql
(SELECT * FROM `table 1`)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table 2`)
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Comment: But I would recommend using `UNION ALL` as there aren't any duplicates and `UNION ALL` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM tableB
```

You need to apply `ORDER BY` to the combined (UNION'ed) resultset, so the final query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tableA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tableB
) ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Comment: thanks for your fast response. i want to order by timestamp ASC. is this work?

Answer (score 0):

select t1.id,t1.timestamp,t1.country,t1.data,t2.id,t2.timestamp,t2.country,t2.data from tableA as t1,tableB as t2 order by t1.timestamp;